# member php on mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

i want display for example the name of the member when he complete login form

```
 <?php "Welcome".$username["username"]."?>
```

but `$username= ?`

i don't know what I put for the variable username. 
so when he finish to complete login form, on article.php i want a message for example : hello with name 
thanks

this is my file : conn.php

```
 <form action="conn.php" method="POST">
    Username:
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"  />
    Password:
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />    
    <input  name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>


<?php
$success = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit']) == "Login" )   
{
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$error = array();
// Username Validation
if(empty($username))
{
$error[] = " Empty or invalid username ";
}
if(empty($password)){
$error[] = "Enter your password"; 
}
if(count($error) == 0){
 $host = 'localhost';  
$database_name = 'projett';
$database_user_name = '';  
$database_password = '';  
 $connection=new MongoClient();
  if($connection){
// Select Database
$database = $connection->$database_name;

// Select Collection
$collection = $database->reg_users;
$user_data= array("username" => $username,"password" => md5($pass));
$result = $collection->findOne($user_data);
if($result){
$success = "You are successully loggedIn";
header("Location: Articles.php");
} 
} else {
die("Mongo DB not installed");
} 
}
} 
?>
```

Article.php :

```
<?php "Welcome " . $username ?>
```

Comment: Can you share the corresponding HTML form as well?

Comment: i have update with my html form

Comment: Actually, why are you trying to print `$username["username"]`? You are assigning `$_POST["username"]` to the `$username` variable, so  you should only print out `$username`. Also, remove the last `."` from the Welcome statement

Comment: you can you tell me what I should write exactly please

Comment: Change this: `<?php "Welcome".$username["username"]."?>` to this: `<?php "Welcome " . $username ?>`

Comment: i have this Undefined variable: username

Comment: Are you trying this in your conn.php? can you paste it here?

Comment: no i try on article.php the file conn.php is just login form, so when he finish to complete login form on article.php i want a message for example : hello okay

Answer (score 0):

```
Try:
Follow these steps
1:- add session_start() top of each file
2:- add code in conn.php 
if($result){
$success = "You are successully loggedIn";
$_SESSION["username"] => $username;
header("Location: Articles.php");
} 
3:- add code Articles.php if(!empty($_SESSION["username"])){ echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION["username"];}
```